Properly use nested environments in packages for Bioconductor
I have a first package where I use a dataset downloaded and stored in cache on the fly
via BiocFileCache that it's used as a reference , called a bit everywhere in my code, but that the user can also modify it.
A  second developed package, based on the first one will also make use of this reference.
I found as a convenient solution to use nested environments for this problem but it didn't pass Bioconductor good practices. I use an environment declared under the empty environment on the top of all packages loaded.
First package declare this environment variables in  a zzz.R file:
.onLoad <- function(...) {

    nameEnv <- "My-Env"
    myEnv <- new.env(parent = emptyenv()) 
    attach(myEnv, name = nameEnv)
    assign("nameEnv", nameEnv, envir = as.environment(nameEnv))

    assign("Var-1", "/some/dir/here" , envir = as.environment(nameEnv))
}

In other parts (files) of the code, I sometimes use the following to retrieve content of this variable:
Var1 <- get("Var-1")

and I can decide to rewrite its content:
assign("Var-1", 
        "/some/dir/elsehwhere", envir = as.environment(nameEnv)

This mechanism works.
Major comment of the reviewer was:


If you are using environment variables (or even options), there
should be no need to use assign. Only call Sys.getenv. The user
will set the value of the environment variable on their systems.
You should not need to use get if all your variables are defined
within the function environment and in that case, you simply call
the object by name.


I don't know how to correct that without using assign or Sys.getenv and follow good
pratices of development.
Update : I wrote Sys.getenv whereas it should have been get. Sorry.

FYI, “environment variables” are something completely different, and unrelated to what you are doing.

Your usage of get() is unnecessary: instead of Var1 <- get("Var-1") you can write Var1 <- `Var-1` . And if you use a syntactically valid variable name you don’t need the backticks either.

The real issue in your code is the use of attach(). attach() modifies global state (specifically via the search path), and that’s (with a few exceptions) not allowed in packages — both on CRAN and on Bioconductor.
Luckily this seems to be completely unnecessary for your purposes anyway. Here’s what you could/should do instead:

Create the environment inside your package’s namespace (let’s call this package A).
Refer to that environment by its variable name instead of via as.environment()
Create functions for reading and writing values inside that environment, and export these functions so that they can be used from other packages.

Here’s a rough outline:
store = new.env(parent = emptyenv())

.onLoad = function (lib, pkg) {
  store$var1 = "/some/dir/here"
}

#' @export
read = function (name) {
  get(name, envir = store)
}

#' @export
write = function (name, value) {
  assign(name, value, envir = store)
}

And now you can for example use A::read("var1").
You could also export the store environment itself, to allow users to write A::store$var1; however, R’s syntax forbids direct assignment via mystore::store$var1 = "new value" (this is arguably (…) a bug in the R interpreter but fixing it has been deemed to complex, with too little usefulness). So for assignment you’d need to either create a temporary alias:
store = A::store
store$var1 = "new value"

… or resort to using assign().

Does using assignInMyNamespace in a specfic function could be an alternative to redefine an exported variable. Because here you are still using  assign  or  get  that reviewers doesn't want to be applied.

As an example, the lattice package saves lattice options in a private environment .LatticeEnv defined in:
https://github.com/cran/lattice/blob/master/R/zzz.R
User facing functions lattice.options and lattice.getOption set and read the contents and can be found in:
https://github.com/cran/lattice/blob/master/R/settings.R

Interesting ! Since assign and get are still required so this probably be discussed a little bit more with the reviewer. Don't see how much that is different from my strategy. Not clear to me also how setting from outside is done. Using a environment is not so much prohibited finally in a package but hard to decipher the good practices.

@ZheFrench assignInMyNamespace() does work, but I find it easier to maintain a mutable environment (as shown in my answer). Additionally, assignInMyNamespace() does lots of work that is completely unnecessary in this case, making it conceptually very bloated. I prefer bespoke code, rather than “Swiss army knife” code that does 100 different things, of which one kinda-sorta aligns with what we want to do.

@ZheFrench Regarding the use of assign() and get(), I refer to my comments under your question. The reviewer comment regarding assign() vs Sys.setenv() is caused by a misunderstanding due to incorrect terminology (“environment variable”). And the comment about get() is what I also noted: if the name is known in the code, there’s no need to use get("name"). Just use name directly.
